# Translate "with this", from Visual FoxPro, to Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-foxpro

Somebody knows how to translate "with this", from Visual FoxPro, to Python 3 ?
also, is there a place where programmers from VFP deal with Python?
Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct translation. You need to write it in its entirety. For example, if you have:

```
with this
  .Color = x
  .Height = 10
  .Width = 20
endwith
```

You would write it as:

```
   self.Color = x
   self.Height = 10
   self.Width = 20
```

Check dabodev if it is still active. That guy (Ed Leafe) is a former VFP guy.